# Google Analytics "Unexpected token )"

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I copy-pasted Google Analytics code and I'm getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`.

Here is code:

```
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Error is in this line: `i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),`.

What to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing an opening parenthesis on that line. Try the following:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Smarty` template engine and get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` use the `{literal}` tags:

```
<script>
    {literal}
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    {/literal}
</script>
```